# Serve PDF file using ASP.NET with custom filename

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, pdf-generation, filenames

I currently have a page ReportPDF.aspx which creates a PDF and writes it to the response. I set the filename using the Content-Disposition header. However, if someone uses "Save link as..." on the link, it still saves the file as ReportPDF.aspx.

How can I use Report.pdf as filename, while still dynamically creating the PDF?

Comment: Can you post the code that u have written for that link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by linking to

```
/ReportPDF.aspx/d6bea1cb-c630-47d6-8735-db7b72713fde/ReportData.pdf
```

And using the `Request.PathInfo` variable to get the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's a behaviour of the browser that the client is using - some will (correctly) use the content-disposition header and some won't... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use URL rewriting so that the URL is actually Report.pdf, which is then rewritten to ReportPDF.aspx server-side?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and have it work with "clean" names :

- no spaces
- only letters and numbers